# Show dialog from Application

Tags: android

I have a class that extends `Application`, in the `onCreate` method I load some stuff from a DB and it doesn't make sense so do it asynchronously, because the app is useless without that data. 
1. problem: when the loading takes somes seconds, Android will show ANR. 
2. problem: can I show a dialog from the extended application class?

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

and

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

both resultet in

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.skelett.GlobalApp: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Should I probably do all the loading stuff in the `onCreate` method of my first `Activity`?
How can I prevent ANR when I *do* want to block the UI until my stuff is loaded?

Comment: Are you writing this code for AsyncTask ??

Comment: Don't create dialogs using `getApplicationContext()`. Dialog needs an Activity context to be attached to the screen. And the other thing, to load the data without showing ANR just use AsyncTask or some other class which does the work on background thread.

Answer (score 1):

you should never allow your application to freeze. NEVER. Do the loading stuff in `AsyncTask` and show the user some progress, add the option for the user to cancel the loading. If it's useless without the data, inform the user that he should wait for this process to finish and start it again if the user confirm, otherwise just exit from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your design. I'd suggest that you move the long running task to it's own thread ([AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or Thread) and start your application with a splash/loading activity that waits until your long running tasks are done before transitioning to your main activity. Another good reference regarding long running background tasks: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You should always do such operations on a different thread. You could display a progress bar while the data loads to show that something is happening. This way you donot keep the user guessing on what exactly is happening. You could show a meaningful message in the progressBar saying that "data is loading" which will be good enough.

Avoid doing long operations on UI thread. Use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. OR you if the data to be loaded is on the first screen of the app you can show a SplashScreen when the app starts and during the SplashScreen display fetch the data in the background, so that its ready to be displayed when the first screen of the app shows up.

Read [Keeping your app responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers have covered you would be better loading your data in an `AsyncTask` the reason for your crash when trying to display a `ProgressDialog` is that `Application` contexts can't create UI elements, you need to do this with an `Activity` context.

An easy way to accomplish this is set a flag when the data finishes loading, when your first screen starts it can display the dialog if the flag hasn't been set yet. You can also send a `Broadcast` when the data is loaded so your `Activity` knows to hide the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Your are approaching the problem wrong:
What you should do is start loading data in the first Activity you display and in that Activity show a progress bar/dialog to inform the user that she/he has to wait.

If the loading takes some time (let's say could take >1s) I would suggest you to use `IntentService` in combination with `ResultReceiver` instead of `AsyncTask` because it is a more robust model (for instance, no problems with orientation changes).

You can see an example in the code of the app I've open sourced: http://bit.ly/ZR2n8R